# Import Console class on intellij

Tags: java, class, import, console

How can I import the Console class to the IntelliJ editor? I have looked this up in various places but cannot find the solution anywhere. I apologize if this is a dumb question but I have nowhere else to go. Thanks.

Comment: Are you asking how to write an `import` statement? If yes, please read your Java Guide on the topic. Or read the [Java Tutorials](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/usepkgs.html). --- Or are you asking which package the `Console` class is in? If yes, do a web search for [`java 8 Console`](https://www.google.com/search?q=java+8+Console), which will lead you to the [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/Console.html), that shows the package name.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you already have a working environment, type in "Console" and press enter. It should add the import statement automatically.

If this doesn't work, add in the beginning "import java.io.Console;"